# Remove default html header tags from flexdahboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'd like to use higher version of boostrap 4.0.0 in flexdashboard and refer to desired version using

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    self_contained: false
    includes:
    in_header: head.html
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
````

```

where `head.html` contains the new header.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Adding the new headers using head.html works, but I'm not able to suppress the default bootstrap and jquery that rmarkdown uses.

I tried `htmltools::suppressDependencies("bootstrap")` inside the flexdashboard content but that didn't work.

Comment: There may be a better way to do this so I will be watching this question, because when I need to modify the header, I always knit the file and then read the lines of the html file, then `gsub` the thing I want to change, then write it back out to html.  If that gets you where you need to be I can post an example.